# Designing API for internal and remote usage in the Django app

Tags: python, django, algorithm, api

I am starting web project that should be very flexible and modular and definitely will grow much in the future. As we plan to provide an api to other developers I started thinking that maybe it is a good idea to implement all the methods as api and provide functionality to  use them remotely and internally.

For instance, say we want to extract all registered Users. So we design method in api, like get_all_users,which maybe available via REST or internal invocation. The problem is I cannot figure out how to distinguish access from internal usage and remote usage, as I should take into consideration also speed of internal invocation,code reusage and checking of user permissions(secret keys for api access, etc). What are the best practices? How to organize such API?

Comment: if you implement the api in the views, you get a `HttpRequest` object that should contain info on the client (sans spoofing, of course)

Answer (score 3):

So to build the API, [Tastypie](http://tastypieapi.org) or [Piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home). These let you write 'resources' (which are basically API versions of the views) - instead of returning httpresponses you just return objects which piston/tastypie convert into json or xml or yaml or whatever your favorite data-language is.

**Securing the access**: Consider decorating any resources which contain confidential information with the @login_required or @staff_member_required decorator as appropriate.

You might even want to go a step further and write a decorator to check that the staff user is using https (whereas you might allow a normal user to use any connection type).

Comment: I second this. I have used Piston a few times, and I have always been happy with it. There is a unfortunate lack of documentation outside of the Piston wiki however, but it is still relatively easy to learn and implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not considered it yet I recommend to use [Tastypie](http://tastypieapi.org) to set up an API with django.
In order to distinguish between your internal and remote usage maybe you can simply design a different URL scheme.